# Website is partially loading - caught SIGTERM

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, logging

I am getting the following error which is RANDOM. Restarting Apache solves the problem.

```
[Fri Jan 02 16:19:21.854040 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18591] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 02 16:19:22.872284 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 11172] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 02 16:19:22.904651 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 11173] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 02 16:19:22.905293 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 11173] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
```

How can I find out what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Apache site (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html)

> Upon startup of httpd, it looks for the file suexec in the directory
>   defined by the --sbindir option (default is
>   "/usr/local/apache/sbin/suexec"). If httpd finds a properly configured
>   suEXEC wrapper, it will print the following message to the error log:
>
> [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /path/to/suexec) If you
>   don't see this message at server startup, the server is most likely
>   not finding the wrapper program where it expects it, or the executable
>   is not installed setuid root.
>
> If you want to enable the suEXEC mechanism for the first time and an
>   Apache HTTP Server is already running you must kill and restart httpd.
>   Restarting it with a simple HUP or USR1 signal will not be enough.
>
> If you want to disable suEXEC you should kill and restart httpd after
>   you have removed the suexec file.

I have removed my suexec file and restarted apache